# why is this regex expression returning false?

Tags: r, rstudio, grepl

My understanding is both of the below grepl regex statements are supposed to be searching the given numeric value for 4 digits from 0-9.

I'm trying to get my head round why the first grepl returns TRUE and the second returns FALSE. The only difference between the numeric numbers is i have added an extra zero onto the second numeric. I thought they would both return TRUE.

```
grepl("\\d{4}", 999900000)

grepl("\\d{4}", 9999000000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening with the following two `grepl` calls is that R is doing an implicit cast of your *numeric* inputs to character, using `as.character`.  So, the following two calls are identical to this:

```
grepl("\\d{4}", as.character(999900000))
grepl("\\d{4}", as.character(9999000000))
```

which becomes:

```
grepl("\\d{4}", "999900000")
grepl("\\d{4}", "9.999e+09")
```

You can clearly see that the second number doesn't actually four digits in it, after it has been converted to a string.  To avoid this, always use regex against actual *text*.  In this case, use:

```
grepl("\\d{4}", "999900000")
[1] TRUE
grepl("\\d{4}", "9999000000")
[1] TRUE
```